# Why isn't tmplItem() giving my data back?

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

If I had any, I'd be tearing my hair out at this one.

Basically, why isn't this bit of jQuery templating working?

http://jsfiddle.net/PTBak/1/

I've used templating before and I can't see the difference / why it's not returning the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are trying to access your tmplItem on something that was not generated by tmpl : the #content container. You are putting your generated content inside it and the #content element doesn't have anything to do with the generated content.

The best approach is to wrap your whole template into a single element and access that element to get the tmplItem(). In your example, I wrapped your template into a #myItem div and access this element instead because it was generated by jQuery.tmpl

http://jsfiddle.net/PTBak/3/

Comment: If you are using Firefox with the Firebug extension, I strongly suggest also installing the Firequery extension. It adds jQuery-specific things to Firebug so, for example, when you inspect an element you can see if there's any jQuery-related data or events attached to that DOM element. It's very helpful in debugging jQuery